# Model methods in HAPI Waterline

Tags: javascript, node.js, waterline, hapi.js

I would like to perform a query in a model method on the corresponding model. Is there a way that i can retrieve a model without going through the request variable?

My user model looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    identity: 'user',
    tableName: 'user',
    connection: 'simple',
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            columnName: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: 'email',
            unique: true,
            columnName: 'email',
            required: true
        },
        password: 'string',
        toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.password;
            return obj;
        },
    },

    isMarriedTo: function(userId, partnerId, cb) {

        // I want to work with the User model
        User
        .findOne({"id": userId})
        .exec(function(err, user){
            //logic
        });
    },
};
```

As you can see, in the function `isMarried` I am trying to user the current User model. However User is undefined (and i can't use require on it?)

Plugins used:
- Dogwater